# Is there a way to render a SDL2 font as monospaced?

Tags: rust, sdl-2

My project is a stopwatch and non-monospaced fonts shake because of the differences between character sizes when running. I have tried `font.set_hinting(sdl2::ttf::Hinting::Mono);` but it does not seem to do anything.

Comment: Hinting just slightly adjusts the shape of symbols (mono hinting specifically is supposed to improve how they look with antialiasing disabled; here mono means monochrome, not monospaced). The easiest solution is to draw each digit separately, at whatever spacing you want. You could also edit your font (e.g. with FontForge) to make it monospaced.

Comment: You could try disabling kerning via [TTF_SetFontKerning](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf.html#SEC28) on an opened Font pointer. This would only work (if at all) if you are rendering complete strings and not individual glyphs.

Comment: Perfect! `set_kerning` works for regular text, although outlines still are buggy because the width is different than normal characters

Comment: @MarkBenningfield (you might want to post that as an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that to render a font as fixed-width (monospace), use a fixed-width font! Fixed- or variable-width is an attribute of the font, not the renderer.

However, if you call [TTF_SetFontKerning](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf.html#SEC28) with an open Font pointer to disable kerning,

`TTF_SetFontKerning(font, 0);`

the renderer will use a fixed spacing between the characters in a string. Note that this only works when rendering complete strings, not single glyphs.

The result will look anywhere from acceptable to really crappy, depending on the glyphs in the actual font used.

Comment: Disabling kerning doesn't make fonts monospaced. It may work on some specific fonts on certain characters, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: I agree. That was the point of the first sentence.

Comment: What you could do is (what @HolyBlackCat said) and draw each individual character, which will allow you to distinguish each character rectangle. For doing this, though, it is slow to draw each character to the screen so you should load them into a single texture first and then draw that instead.

Comment: Yes, that's probably what we will eventually go for if we end up working with outlines